# Having trouble writing a url pattern in django

Tags: python, regex, django

I want to match the following url pattern `/posts/tagged/tag-name/`

I've tried a few different patterns but Django splits out a 404 because it the url doesn't match any patterns.

This is the pattern I pulled from the docs http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/use_url_patterns_and_views_in_django/

```
(r'^posts/tagged/(?P[-w]+)/$', 'blog.view.posts_by_tag')
```

Can anyone one help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(r'^posts/tagged/(?P<tag>[-\w]+)/$', 'blog.view.posts_by_tag')
```

Your `posts_by_tag` view will then receive a keyword argument called `tag`.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I had <tag> in there but it may have been stripped out. I was missing the \w part.